# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Variable Nested/Composed/Expression

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-keyvault

I have a release pipeline with a variable, but there doesn't seem to be any way to set the value of that variable to something that's evaluated at release time. For example, another variable.

Here's a real example:

[image]

All I want to do is set the value of `MyExpressionBasedVariable` to the value of `MyOtherVariable`.

All the docs and examples online seem to suggest it's possible, but I can't get it to work. I always end up with the literal string rather than the evaluated value.

I've tried using these different syntaxes:

- `$(MyOtherVariable)`
- `$[variables['MyOtherVariable']]`
- `${{variables['MyOtherVariable']}}`

I've seen that you can define custom tasks to set variable names as part of the pipeline but this seems massively overkill.

Essentially all I want to do is rename a key vault secret to a different variable name for convention-based XML variable replacement in config files.

E.g. I have a secret called `this-is-a-secret-name-which-is-a-different-naming-convention-to-my-connectionstrings` but I need it in a variable called `MySecret-ConnectionString`.

## How do I use the value of another variable in a release pipeline variable?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special. `Foo` = `$(Bar)` and `Bar` = `Baz` will result in `Foo` = `Baz`. It could have something to do with your usage of the variables. Can you update your question with actual usage?

Comment: That’s what I thought but it doesn’t work as far as I can tell. Does that only work for build pipelines rather than release or should it be the same?

Comment: It's the same. I do it all the time. I'm working on release definitions **right now** that do this.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Not sure what I’m doing wrong. Could it be that I’m using a variable from a variable group where I have the tick box enabled for allowing access to all pipelines? I.e it’s kind of inherited and not explicitly imported into the pipeline?

Comment: @DanielMann after some playing around I can confirm that's what it is! If I "link" the variable group in the pipeline, it works. If I "unlink" the variable group it stops working and I just get the literal name `$(MyOtherVariable)`, even though I can use the same variable directly within pipeline tasks - it just doesn't work within the pipeline variables screen. Facepalm.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I use the value of another variable in a release pipeline variable?

As I test, what you set should be work. You can try to follow below steps to check if you still have this issue:

- Create a new release pipeline **without** link any variable group.
- Set the Variable like following:

  [image]
- Add a Run Inline Powershell task to output the value of the Variable:

  ```
  Write-Output 'The value of MyExpressionBasedVariable is $(MyExpressionBasedVariable)'

  Write-Output 'The value of $(MyOtherVariable) is $(MyOtherVariable)'
  ```

Then we could get the log:

[image]

So, what you set should be work, if this still does not work for you, then you need to **make sure that the variable you describe in the question is the variable your actual test**.

**Besides**, at this moment, **the value of nested variables (like `$(TestVar_$(Release.Reason))`) are not yet supported in the build/release pipelines**, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194458/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-set-the-artifact-name-in-my-azure-devops-build-p/56215166#56215166) for some details, so make sure there are no such nested variables in your project.

Hope this helps.