# Substitute variables with variable in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have below variables.

```
variable            value
stage                dev
admin                $($(stage)-admindata)
dev-admindata        4000
```

But these multiple substitutions are not working for variable admin.

Please let me know how to solve this.

admin values should be 4000 when I use it in yaml or in json file, Currently I am getting $(dev-admindata)

Comment: Is *admindata* supposed to be a string or another variable?

Comment: i would have thought it needs to be `$(stage)-admindata`

Comment: @ArchitectJamie It is another variable.

Comment: @4c74356b41 No, I have to do multiple substitutions. Now I have added it  again

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, the value of nested variables (like $($(stage)-admindata)) are not yet supported in the build/release pipelines.

If you want to give different values to the `admin` variable depending on the value of `stage` varibale. As a work around you can write a script in the powershell task to judge, e.g. If the value of the `stage` variable is `dev`, then assign the value of the `dev-admindata` variable to the admin variable.

```
     if ($(stage) -eq "dev"){
       $admin = $(dev-admindata)
     }
     else{
       xxxxx
     }
```

For the similar issue ,you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194458/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-set-the-artifact-name-in-my-azure-devops-build-p/56215166#56215166).

Comment: We don't want this in condition, if nested variables are not yet supported in pipelines then is there any other way so, if we can handle this in YAML or in JSON file. we are using replace token task

Comment: Through testing, it seems that nested variables are also not supported in yaml.