# Retrive Variable in a variable group using another variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have variable group variable as given below

```
 opp453.Name = "Raj"
 pqr325.Name = "Shyam"
```

I know can I retrieve the variable group as below

```
$(opp453.Name) or $(pqr325.Name)
```

If I have another variable

```
$ptrref=opp453 or
$ptrref=pqr325
```

Then how can I refer to this variable inside the first variable

```
$($ptrref.Name)
```

to retrieve the original value

Comment: Where do you want to referred the variable? in script? in pipeline task?

Comment: Has the problem been solved? If so, please accept the solution as the answer so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.If not,please feel free to tell.

Comment: issue not solved

Comment: Did you face with any new problem around this subject? since this kind of operation is not possible and a workaround is provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is impossible to achieve at present because Nested variables are not supported yet in build pipeline/variable group.You can check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215166/12473216) for some more details.

We could also use the same workaround, using InlinePowershell task to determine the value of ptrref, and set the value of opp453.Name/ pqr325.Name according to the value of ptrref.